# Right click and Drag and drop using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am working on a qa automation project using Selenium webdriver.

I need to perform drag and drop on a telerik rad grid for reordering columns and then right click on the grid to save the changes made.

Is there any way i can achieve these using selenium webdriver ?

Thanks.

Comment: In 2013-14, we do it like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210051/how-to-automate-drag-drop-functionality-using-selenium-web-driver

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For drag and drop you may try:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;    
using OpenQA.Selenium;

RemoteWebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement sourceElement = FindElement(By.Id("id1"));
IWebElement targetElement = FindElement(By.Id("id2"));
IWebElement gridElement = FindElement(By.Id("grid"));
action.DragAndDrop(sourceElement, targetElement).Perform(); //drag&drop
Thread.Sleep(500); //if necessary
action.ContextClick(gridElement).Perform(); //right click
```

or you may use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Thanks. I am still having issues with right click. The right click menu disappears as soon as it is displayed. I have implemented it like this:

var context= action.ContextClick(gridElement).Build();
context.Perform();

I also used sleep so that the menu would not disappear, but thats not working.

Answer (score 3):

you can click in same action when it disappears as soon as it appears... just like

```
action.ContextClick(element).Click(x axis, y axis).build.perform();
```

it will works..