# How to automate drag & drop functionality using Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

How to automate drag & drop functionality using `Selenium WebDriver` in java?

Comment: can we have an accepted answer please

Comment: How this question never got closed to this point I don't understand...and so many upvotes??? No demonstration of research, no code samples, ... this is give me teh codez.

Answer (score 57):

There is a page documenting Advanced User Interactions; which has a lot of great examples on how to generate a sequence of actions,  [you can find it here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Advanced-User-Interactions)

```
// Configure the action
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
   .click(someElement)
   .click(someOtherElement)
   .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);

// Then get the action:
Action selectMultiple = builder.build();

// And execute it:
selectMultiple.perform();
```

or

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
   .moveToElement(otherElement)
   .release(otherElement)
   .build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: Isn't `.moveToElement(otherElement)` unnecessary when you use `.release(otherElement)`?

Comment: builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
   .click(someElement)
   .click(someOtherElement)
   .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);

// Then get the action:
Action selectMultiple = builder.build();

// And execute it:
selectMultiple.perform();   Is this code for drag and drop? I think, it's for multiple selection.

Comment: when i try to run this i get :- Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds, any idea how to solve it

Answer (score 37):

Selenium has pretty good documentation. [Here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#drag-and-drop) is a link to the specific part of the API you are looking for.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source")); 

WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target"));

(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

Comment: always prefer to add code/example from the target link, the link might get changed/dead in near future and hence, the answer might become invalid for future users. I've added it for now.

Comment: Why the extra parenthesis around `(new Actions(driver))`?

Comment: Really helps for drag and drop!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Drag and drop can be implemented like this...

```
public ObjectPage filter(int lowerThreshold, int highThreshold) {
    Actions action = new Actions(getWebDriver());
    action.dragAndDropBy(findElement(".className .thumbMin"), lowerThreshold, 0).perform();
    waitFor(elementIsNotDisplayed("#waiting_dialog"));

    action.dragAndDropBy(findElement(".className .thumbMax"), highThreshold, 0).perform();
    waitFor(elementIsNotDisplayed("#waiting_dialog"));
    return this;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Selenium has so many options to perform drag and drop.

In Action class we have couple of method which will perform the same task.

I have listed the possible solution please have a look.

http://learn-automation.com/drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver-using-actions-class/

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(fDriver);
    builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
        .click(element)
        .dragAndDrop(element, elementDropped)
        .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);

        Action selected = builder.build();

        selected.perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

one more way is to use `draganddrop()` like this

```
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source"));
      WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target"));

     (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing code given below

```
package com.kagrana;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class DragAndDrop {
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException{
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#treebox1 > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td.standartTreeRow > span")).click();
        WebElement elementToMove = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#treebox1 > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td.standartTreeRow > span"));
        WebElement moveToElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#treebox1 > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.standartTreeRow > span"));
        Actions dragAndDrop = new Actions(driver);
        Action action = dragAndDrop.dragAndDrop(elementToMove, moveToElement).build();
        action.perform();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    WebElement fromElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("SourceElement"));
    WebElement toElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("TragetElement"));
    Actions action = new Actions(WebDriver);
    Action dragDrop = action.dragAndDrop(fromElement, toElement).build();
    dragDrop.perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would  do it like this in Perl using Selenium::Remote::Driver.

```
my $sel = <>;  #selenium handle
my $from_loc = <fromloc>;
my $to_loc   = <toloc>;

my $from_element = $sel->find_element($from_loc);
my $to_element = $sel->find_element($to_loc);

# Move mouse to from element, drag and drop
$sel->mouse_move_to_location(element=>$from_element);
$sel->button_down(); # Holds the mouse button on the element
$sel->mouse_move_to_location(element=>$to); # Move mouse to the destination
$sel->button_up();
```

This should do it!

Answer (score 0):

For `xpath` you can use the above commands like this :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter xpath of source element here")); 
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter xpath of target here"));
(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;    /*
      Move only
      @param o WebElement  to move
      @param d WebElement  destination element
    */
    m.drag={o,d->
       def lo=o.location;
       def ld=d.location;
       int di=ld.y - lo.y;
       int inc,lim
       if (di<0) 
       { inc=-1
         lim=ld.y+d.size.height
       }
       else
       { inc=1
         lim=ld.y
       }
       def fes={
                int act=o.location.y;
                println "act=${act} ${lim}";
                if (inc > 0)
                  return !(act>lim)
                else 
                  return !(act<lim)
               }
         def b =new Actions(driver);
            b.clickAndHold(o).perform();
            while ( fes() ){
              b.moveByOffset(0,inc);b.perform();sleep(20);
            }
            //
            b.release(m.ori).perform();
    }//drag
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has pretty good documentation. Here is a link to the specific part of the API you are looking for:

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source"));`

`WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target"));`

`(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();`

This is to drag and drop a single file, How to drag and drop multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I used below piece of code.
Here **dragAndDrop(x,y)** is a method of Action class. Which takes two parameters (x,y), source location, and target location respectively

```
try {
                System.out.println("Drag and Drom started :");
                Thread.sleep(12000);
                Actions actions = new Actions(webdriver);
                WebElement srcElement = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("source Xpath"));
                WebElement targetElement = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("Target Xpath"));
                actions.dragAndDrop(srcElement, targetElement); 
                actions.build().perform();
                System.out.println("Drag and Drom complated :");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                resultDetails.setFlag(true);
            }
```