# Selenium Webdriver Java - looking for alternatives for Actions and Robot when performing drag-and-drop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I first tried Actions class and the drag-and-drop does work on different elements, however it was unable to locate the a specific draggable element on it's exact screen/webpage position.

Here's the code I've used:

```
    Point loc = driver.findElement(By.id("thiselement")).getLocation();
    System.out.println(loc);
    WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.id("thiselement"));
    Actions test = new Actions(driver);
    test.dragAndDropBy(drag, 0, 60).build().perform();
```

I checked the element with it's pixel location and it prints (837, -52), which was somewhere on top of the webpage and was pixels away from the actual element.

Then I tried using the Robot class and works perfectly fine on my script, but can only provide constant successful runs on a single test machine, running it with a different machine with different screen resolution and screen size will render the script to fail due to the dependency of Robot on the pixel location of the element.

The sample code of the Robot script I'm using:

Robot dragAndDrop = new Robot();

```
  dragAndDrop.mouseMove(945, 166); //actual pixel location of the draggable element
  dragAndDrop.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        sleep(3000);
  dragAndDrop.mouseMove(945, 226);
  dragAndDrop.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        sleep(3000);
```

Is there any alternative for Actions and Robot to automate drag-and-drop? Or maybe a help on working the script to work on Actions as I really can't use Robot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what type of element you want to use the drag-and-drop? some jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to drag and drop,

```
Actions test= new Actions(driver);

builder.clickAndHold("thisElement").moveToElement("targetElement")

.release("targetElement")

.build().perform();
```

This SO post will help you better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210051/how-to-automate-drag-drop-functionality-using-selenium-web-driver)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I also tried that before but it still doesn't work. :(