# How to properly simulate drag and drop in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a test that performs a drag and drop.

My code currently:

```
WebElement element;
By mainSelector, secondarySelector;
Actions action;

action = new Actions(driver);

mainSelector = By.cssSelector("tbody.naam tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)");
secondarySelector = By.cssSelector("tbody.bedrijf tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)");

action.click(driver.findElement(mainSelector));

action.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(mainSelector))
    .moveToElement(driver.findElement(secondarySelector), 5, 5)
    .perform();
action.release(driver.findElement(secondarySelector));

action.perform();

action.dragAndDropBy(driver.findElement(mainSelector), 300, 300).perform();

action.dragAndDrop(driver.findElement(mainSelector), driver.findElement(secondarySelector)).perform();
```

But this does not do anything.
I have added multiple performs so be sure that that is not the problem.
I have added an offset because i read that this sometimes is buggy.
I used firefox for testing.

Comment: Kindly check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210051/how-to-automate-drag-drop-functionality-using-selenium-web-driver

Answer (score -1):

If you want to drag mainSelector into secondarySelector, you can do something like this

`Method 1`

```
mainSelector = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tbody.naam tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)"));
secondarySelector = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tbody.bedrijf tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)"));

action = new Actions(driver)
action.dragAndDrop(mainSelector, secondarySelector).perform();
```

`Method 2`

```
action.clickAndHold(mainSelector).moveToElement(secondarySelector).release().build().perform();
```

Both method would do the task.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: the `dragAndDrop` function accepts only WebElements right? Not `By` selectors?

Comment: I have added it to the list of tries but it is not working for me here, sadly.

Comment: @Funonly  : Can you show your complete implementation for the same?

Comment: @Rupesh You mean the javascript?