# I am not able to drag and drop using action class .Tried many solution in action class.is there is any other solution in webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please help for solution other then action class..i have to drag and drop element ;from element; to 'To element' in java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automate drag & drop functionality using Selenium WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210051/how-to-automate-drag-drop-functionality-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use '[Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)' for drag and drop. It's quite straight forward. An example of how I'm using it which may actually work for you...

```
// Location of your first element
Point coordinates1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your element xpath")).getLocation();

// Location of your second Element
Point coordinates2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your element xpath")).getLocation();

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.setAutoDelay(2000);
    robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);

    // go to the location of the first element
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates1.getX(), coordinates1.getY());

    robot.delay(500);

    // Press the mouse on the first location
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

    robot.delay(500);

    // Move the mouse to the second location
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates2.getX(), coordinates2.getY());

    // Release the mouse on the second location
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK)
```

Comment: can any body help me with javascript solution for drag and drop