# why my selenium cant drag and drop in any sense

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image: enter image description]

I'm doing automated testing and I want to drag the left document '高级元素' to the canvas cell right in the picture. however what commands I use like drag_and_drop, click and hold. the document is never dragged to the canvas cell.

```
    drag_1 = gt("//button[@class='mat-icon-button']")
    drag_a = gt("//div[@class='dynamic-container']")
    action.drag_and_drop(drag_1, drag_a).perform()
```

This is my code to drag `drag_1` to `drag_a`  but it's not effective.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14222645/3110529)

To summarise what it says (C#):

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
   .moveToElement(otherElement)
   .release(otherElement)
   .build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

In Python this will translate to

```
click_and_drag = ActionChains(driver)
click_and_drag.click_and_hold(someElement)
click_and_drag.move_to_element(otherElement)
click_and_drag.release(otherElement)
click_and_drag.perform()
```