# Drag and drop not working - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to drag an element into another element using Selenium WebDriver but it's not working. 
We tried with different solutions as mentioned below :

Application was built on Anjular4

```
WebElement From = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("")));
WebElement To = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='avpContainer']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(From).moveToElement(To).click(To).release().build().perform();





WebElement From = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("")));
WebElement To = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='avpContainer']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(From).release(To).build().perform();

WebElement From = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("")));
WebElement To = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='avpContainer']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.dragAndDrop(From, To).build().perform();

//Setup robot
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.setAutoDelay(50);
//Maximized browser:
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement dragElement = d.findElement('drag element');
Actions builder = new Actions(d);
builder.dragAndDropBy(dragElement,x, y).build().perform();
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210051/how-to-automate-drag-drop-functionality-using-selenium-webdriver-java

Comment: Try giving perform() in the next line like below, sometime it worked for me,.....builder.clickAndHold(From).moveToElement(To).click(To).release().build();
builder.perform();

Comment: @Vincent We also tried as suggested by you, not working for us

If the application is build on HTML5 drag and drop feature using selenium will not been supported?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(From)
.moveToElement(To)
.release(To)
.build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: we tried as suggested by you, still not working for us

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop functionality won't work, if application is built on HTML5.

So, we can make this work with the support of draganddrop.js