# Load json manually in chrome://tracing

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, trace

I have a trace events JSON data and I want to view it using `chrome://tracing`. However, I don’t want to load the JSON every time.

Is there a way I can pass the JSON data to `chrome://tracing` so that without manually clicking load data all my data gets loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Trace-viewer](https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult/blob/master/tracing/README.md) tool currently loads the JSON file in 3 ways:

- When **recording** a new trace
- When **loading** the file via the load button after the file has been picked
- When **dropping** the file into the tab (drag & drop)

All of these do a **one-time** update to the active trace.

---

### Technical details

Look at the [profiling_view](https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult/blob/cb66d9d95233c2e1a399a00e0084426334db1c30/tracing/tracing/ui/extras/about_tracing/profiling_view.html#L307) and notice

```
 tr.ui.b.readFile(file).then(
 ...
    this.setActiveTrace(file.name, data);
```

and a few variations on calls to **setActiveTrace** from beginRecording , onLoadClicked_ and dropHandler_ .

---

### Solution suggestions

Yes, there are a few  ways in which you can *pass the json data to chrome://tracing (i.e. trace viewer) without manually clicking load data* .

Depending on how much effort you want to put into it:

1. Don't manually click load but drag and drop the file
2. Automate the drag & drop ([example with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14210051/4807777)) based on a script which watches for file changes to the JSON
3. Automate the load based on file changes
4. [Contribute to Trace Viewer yourself](https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult/blob/master/tracing/README.md) and add this feature. See [the tracing ecosystem explainer](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QADiFe0ss7Ydq-LUNOPpIf6z4KXGuWs_ygxiJxoMZKo/edit#) and [contributing](https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md). Note it is now part of the Catapult project in GitHub.

See [fswatch - a cross-platform file change monitor.](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, if you can relax the requirement that you have to open it with Chrome-Tracing. [**Speedscope**](https://speedscope.app) is a nice replacement and can be easily started from the command line.

> For offline use, or convenience in the terminal, you can also install speedscope via npm:
>
> ```
> npm install -g speedscope
> ```
>
> Invoking speedscope /path/to/profile will load speedscope in your default browser. [Source](https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope)

`speedscope <my-chrome-tracing.json>` opens the file.

[image]

Speedscopes offers different views but not sometimes not the same view as Chrome-Tracing. So it might not be the right choice for all use cases.

Comment: lightweight and swift, recommend, https://www.speedscope.app/ also eases installation!

Answer (score 0):

[this GopherCon video](https://youtu.be/nok0aYiGiYA) shows another solution I guess, which is to load into the browser an HTML page, probably with embedded Javascript in it, that “loads” the trace file. Although I suspect not from a disk file but by “serving” it directly via a custom http server.